Как сделать проверку на наличие у пользователя прав?
Как сделать проверку на наличие прав у пользователя в html?
В представлении (views.py) как сделать такую проверку понятно, но как сделать непосредственно на странице, как, например, с user.is_superuser?
Или в Django нет встроенного шаблонизатора для проверки на права?

если речь идет о проверке прав пользователя в template, то можно как-то так '{% if perms.appname.add_modelname %}' - в этом случае проверяются права на добавление данных modelname

а вообще, все есть в документации: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions

@strawdog действительно, все работает, и за ссылку большое спасибо
